# css make fixed height dropdown scrollable

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, keyboard, scroll

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
```

the `div` is fixed height, and scrollable if the `ul` height is bigger than its height. I wrote some code so I can use arrowup and arrowdown to navigate the `li` . The problem is when I use keyboard to select the items that are out of the height, the div doesn't scroll to the position automatically.

Is there any way to implement it?

Comment: How are you implementing it at the moment?

Comment: I didn't. I'd like to know if there is an easy way to do this without writing javascript code to position the scrollbar.

Comment: You said you wrote some code so you could use the arrow keys to navigate, so yes, you have.

Comment: It just highlights the one I navigated to. When it goes to the one, say right under the last one that is visible. It doesn't scroll down so I can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say `obj.scrollTop = selectedChildObj.offsetTop` to automatically set the height.

Comment: thx. $('selectedChildObj').position().top is what I need in my case.